Find weights and bias of Discrete Perceptron
I am studying for an exam and came across this question which I am unable to solve.
How do I find the corresponding weights and biases.
I understand that it is a perceptron so the activation function is sigmoid = 1 / (1 + e^-x)
I tried using the data points and forming equations like u = 2w1 + 0w2 + b etc. and then f(u) = 1/(1 + e^(2w1 + b)) etc but didn't get anywhere with that.

